# Problem in the derivation of replica partition function of Hopfield network.

Tags: summation, exponential-function, mathematical-physics, neural-networks, exponential-sum

While I was following the derivation of the replica partition function of Hopfield network from [here](https://medium.com/@hiroku007/replica-theory-of-hopfield-networks-3677342a023f), I have found something strange explanation. Due to the independence of $s_{i}$'s, the following term:
$$\sum_{s=\pm1}\exp\left( \beta\sum_{a=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}m_{a}\xi_{i}s^{a}_{i} + \frac{\alpha\beta^2}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{a\neq b}r_{ab}s^{a}_{i}s^{b}_{i} \right)$$
can be represented in the following form, where the indices are removed:
$$\exp\left[ N\ln\left(\sum_{s=\pm1}\exp\left( \beta\sum_{a=1}^{n}m_{a}\xi s^{a} + \frac{\alpha\beta^2}{2}\sum_{a\neq b}r_{ab}s^{a}s^{b} \right)\right) \right].$$
But how can it be possible? For instance, the following equation is generally true.
$$e^{Na} + e^{Nb} \neq e^\left(N\ln(e^{a} + e^{b})\right).$$
If the first two terms implies the same thing, then, I guess, some kind of approximation should be introduced. Could someone please help me?

Comment: In fact, what is going on is $e^{am+bm}$ since the $\sum_i^N$ is in the exponent

Comment: Thanks for the comment! True if we consider the summation over $i$ so that we will have a linear exponent. But if we consider the summation over $s$ which has values $\pm 1$, we are summing up two exponential terms, $e^{Na} + e^{Nb}$. Generally, $e^{Na} + e^{Nb}$ is not equal to $(e^a + e^b)^N$. That's where I am stuck at it.

Comment: The text you refer to is unreadable, I don't think you should trust it. The $\sum_s$ should stay out of the exponential, and possibly convert the expression to a product of $cosh$

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, it is too difficult to read. Apparently, the text written in the website has almost same derivation in the book "The First Landau Institute Summer School, 1993: Selected Proceedings". The equation (10.22) of the book also says the same thing. I also agree with you that it would be much nicer to convert into a product of $\cosh$. However, I'm afraid that it will give totally different self-consistent equations in the end which are already widely used.

Comment: Google link of the [book](https://books.google.hu/books?id=VRNZpCqX2DAC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=hopfield+network+replica+partition+function&source=bl&ots=oMIpGXB_Uz&sig=ACfU3U1Chu7HQHU-Ar4CUikr-Hg2-p8Ixg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxvKbRyKvnAhXDrIsKHUr8BNwQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=hopfield%20network%20replica%20partition%20function&f=false)

Comment: In the book the $log cosh$ is indeed expanded (after 10.17). I think that is the approximation you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer to my question. First of all, the derivation in the [book](https://books.google.hu/books?id=VRNZpCqX2DAC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=hopfield%20network%20replica%20partition%20function&source=bl&ots=oMIpGXB_Uz&sig=ACfU3U1Chu7HQHU-Ar4CUikr-Hg2-p8Ixg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxvKbRyKvnAhXDrIsKHUr8BNwQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=hopfield%20network%20replica%20partition%20function&f=false) is not perfectly correct. It didn't consider an average over the quenched random variable. Anyways, the right form of the first equation in the question is the following.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\{s\}}\left[ \int \exp\left( \beta\sum_{a = 1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}m^{a}\xi_{i}s^{a}_{i} + \frac{\alpha\beta^2}{2}\sum_{a\neq b}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}R_{ab}s^{a}_{i}s^{b}_{i}\right)\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(\xi_{i}) d\xi_{i} \right]
\end{equation}
Then change the order of integral and summation.
\begin{equation}
\int \sum_{\{s\}}\left[\exp\left( \beta\sum_{a = 1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}m^{a}\xi_{i}s^{a}_{i} + \frac{\alpha\beta^2}{2}\sum_{a\neq b}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}R_{ab}s^{a}_{i}s^{b}_{i}\right)\right]\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(\xi_{i}) d\xi_{i}
\end{equation}
Since every $\xi_{i}$'s are independent random variables, and their probability distributions are identical, we get the following without indicies.
\begin{equation}
\left[\int \sum_{\{ s \}}\left[\exp\left( \beta\sum_{a = 1}^{n}m^{a}\xi s^{a} + \frac{\alpha\beta^2}{2}\sum_{a\neq b}^{n}R_{ab}s^{a}s^{b}\right)\right]p(\xi) d\xi\right]^{N}
\end{equation}
Then taking a logarithm and exponential, we obtain something similar equation in the question but with average over quenched random variable.